# time cursor shifted in frames in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, timeline

The time cursor in Video Sequence Editor (VSE) or Timeline is shifted to the right when I right click somewhere in the timeline. The time cursor does not move to the position of the mouse cursor. The shift in frames depends on the position (0 on frame 0, +400 on frame 20000).
Load Factory Settings does not fix it. But a new project does not show this.
Any idea?

Comment: did you play with time remapping before?

Comment: Right to the point! It is exactly my issue, I mistakenly changed the time remapping to 102/100. Changing to 100/100 fixed my issue. I'm so grateful, thank you!

Comment: that happened to me too, before :) although resetting time mapping reverts the weird (and unusable) behaviour, it is perhaps a bug, since imho it makes impossible to work with time remapping AND timeline cursor positioning...